# Unable to get value 'String(34)' from database resultset, index 2

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am getting this error and my pentaho transformation failed. What does index 2 means? and which one is it referring to?

Comment: We do not have enough information. Can you please copy/paste the full stacktrace.

Comment: At first glance the second field or the second row of your database does not fit in a String of length 34. However, this error may be a consequence of the failure of a totally different step.